# Sheet layout after PDF export is different than the one shown in the preview

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a one-page report in Google Sheets. I've organized the text and charts as wanted. When previewing before exporting in PDF, there are no spaces between the charts. After exporting, they somehow shrank/moved.

Is there a way to avoid this?
Thanks

When previewing:

[image: Space between charts - Preview]

After exporting:

[image: Space between charts - Exported PDF]

Comment: Can you share your setup for exporting the PDF (i.e. margins and scales)? I tried it on my side but it seems that the charts in the PDF did not have spaces in between. Can you share a sample file with dummy data so that the community may have a better look at your situation?

Comment: Have you tried zooming in (200%) in Google Sheets when aligning the said charts? I used 200% view when aligning my charts.